# UNIX: copy entire directory structure and only specific file type

Tags: shell, unix, ubuntu, posix

How i can recreate entire directory structure and copy only files with .txt extension if present. I would like to copy the directory or sub-directory even if its empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one line command :)

```
rsync -vapEtogR --progress --stats --log-file="log_file_name.txt" --include '*/' --include '*.txt' --exclude '*' source_path/ destination_path/
```

Use `rsync --help` to know about the options used.

Comment: However, the are duplicated options in the `rsync` command as `-a` already provides `-rlptgoD`.

Answer (score 0):

To create the directory structure:

```
cd source-dir
find . -type d -exec mkdir target-dir/{} \;
```

You can ignore the message that `.` cannot be created.

Then, copy the `txt` files into it:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cp {} target-dir/{} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @choroba. I used this commands 
cd source
find . -type d -exec mkdir /home/superjaggu/Desktop/copy{} \;
But this created copy folder with the name "copy." . any method to remove the . from copy

Comment: @Jaggu: Why did you remove the `/` before `{}`?

Comment: mkdir was throwing an error
mkdir:cannot create directory '/home/superjaggu/Dekstop/copy/./a/a4':No such file or directory

Comment: i found one more method to create directory structure
find ./home -type d -printf "./copy/%P\0" | xargs -0 mkdir -p

Comment: Change the mkdir in the first command to `mkdir -p` also helps. (I added a dot in the second find, a clear typo)

Answer (score 0):

```
cd source-dir
find . -type d -mindepth 1 -exec mkdir target-dir/{} \;
```

to avoid creating directory "." and error "No such file or directory" respectively.

Comment: Cool you're here! But if you want to comment on an answer, please comment on the answer ;)